# Unable to read two files?

Tags: c++, loops

I am writing a program that takes a user command along with a filename, for example command1  or command2 . At the moment, I am guessing there is something wrong with my looping structure because after I use a command on a file, I cant use it on another file anymore.

For example;

```
command1 example.txt
... works...
command1 anotherexample.txt
wrong command! try again!
```

How can I fix the code so that the commands work every time on any file? I know it has something to do with the way I have structured the code, but I can't seem to fix it.

```
while (getline(cin, str1)){

    if (str1 == "bye")
    {
        return 0;

    } else {
        s1.str (str1);
        s1 >> command;
        s1 >> filename;
        ifs.open(filename.c_str()); 

        if (ifs.fail()) {                                                       
            cerr << "ERROR: Failed to open file " << filename << endl;   
            ifs.clear();   

        } else { 

            if (str1 == "command1 " + filename) {
                command1(filename);

            } else if (str1 == "command2 " + filename) {
                command2(filename);                                                                 

            }   else {
                cout << "Wrong command! try again!" << endl;
            } 
        }
        ifs.close();
    }
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Don't forget to click the check mark next to the post if you like the answer

Comment: `ifs.close()` doesnt get called since prompt() is called due to which it might be behaving this way.

Comment: I tried ifs.close() in each method but that didn't work.

Comment: Instead of just "Wrong command", try printout like `cout << "Wrong command [" << str1 << "] -- try again!" << endl;`. Maybe `str1` doesn't contain what you expect it to.

Comment: That doesnt help my problem, I am unable to use a command on two different files. That's what I am trying to fix.

Comment: why aren't you just testing the command? something like `if (command == "command1") ...` instead of `if(str1 == "command1 " + filename) ...`.

Comment: @sparta93: When you want to fix something, the first thing to do is usually to figure out why it doesn't work. Sometimes the reason is not obvious, and you have to inspect some of the intermediate steps in your program. Adding some printout obviously won't make your program suddenly start working, but it might give a clue as to how you can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cin take the argument passed into main and use it as a file name for a `ifsteam`

```
 #include <fstream>


 int main(int argc, char** argv){
    // you may have  a type problem just convert it into the correct type

    std::ifstream file(argv[1]);
    while (getline(file, str1)){
```